# Building opencv_contrib on Windows: "CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake:78"

Tags: cmake, opencv3.0

It's my fist time using cmake-gui to make the source code of opencv_contrib. And I get an error below. I've searched for it for many times,but do not get any useful help. Even I don't know what the error means. I'm not sure whether merely copying some lines of the error to Google to search is right. I'm sincerely hoping your help.

#### The error is :

```
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake:78 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "NOT" "optimized" "C:/Program Files/Python35/libs/python35.lib" "debug" "C:/Program Files/Python35/libs/python35_d.lib" "EQUAL" ""

  Unknown arguments specified
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake:219 (find_python)
  CMakeLists.txt:562 (include)
```

#### The cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake:73-80 is

```
 if(_found)
    set(_version_major_minor "${_version_major}.${_version_minor}")
    if(NOT ANDROID AND NOT APPLE_FRAMEWORK)
      ocv_check_environment_variables(${library_env} ${include_dir_env})
      if(NOT ${${library_env}} EQUAL "")
          set(PYTHON_LIBRARY "${${library_env}}")
      endif()
```

#### note:

- *I get the source code (cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake:73-80) from my own file. And the error comes when I try to click the generate button.*
- My environment is :

  - CPU                  : Intel Pentium 2020E(64X)
  - OS                   : Windows10(64X)
  - opencv_version       : 3.1.0
  - cmake_version        : 3.7.2(win-64X)
  - python_version       : 3.5
  - VisualStudio_version : 2015

**Drives me mad.....**

Comment: Where can I get more information about the error?

Comment: `Where can I get more information about the error?` - By looking into the line of code error refers to (`cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake:78`). It is worth to add this line into the question post.

Comment: thank you.I'll try.

Comment: `I get the source code (cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake:78) from github, but not from my own file. Does it mean I have a damaged file lack of sth?` - It just mean that your file differs from the last revision in repo. Probably, it corresponds to some previous revision, or has been patched. If you don't clone your project directly from github, no need to worry. Please, provide content of the file **on your machine**. The line you add into the post has nothing common with error message, and doesn't help in solving the problem.

Comment: thx~ I'm trying to describe it in more detail. Thank you for your direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that code in `cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake` is incorrect. (It isn't corrected in the repo too).

**Proper** way for **check variable's non-emptiness**:

```
if(NOT "${VAR}" STREQUAL "")
```

In your case *original* lines in `cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake`:

```
if(NOT ${${library_env}} EQUAL "")
      set(PYTHON_LIBRARY "${${library_env}}")
```

should be **rewritten** as:

```
if(NOT "${${library_env}}" STREQUAL "")
      set(PYTHON_LIBRARY ${${library_env}})
```

Explanations are below.

---

The line, to which error message refers

```
if(NOT ${${library_env}} EQUAL "")
```

is a part of function's definition `find_python()`, and `library_env` is the parameter of this function.

The function is called twice: one for *Python2* and one for *Python3*. According to error message, it is second call which fails, and it passes `PYTHON3_LIBRARY` as `library_env` argument.

So errorneous line can be read as:

```
if(NOT ${PYTHON3_LIBRARY} EQUAL "")
```

It tries to check, whether variable is not empty ... but does this **wrong**:

1. If the variable is actually *empty*, CMake completely *omits its dereference*, so the line would be read as

   ```
   if(NOT EQUAL "")
   ```

   which is *incorrect* call to `if()` command.
2. In you case, content of the variable `PYTHON3_LIBRARY` is a *list*:

   ```
   optimized "C:/Program Files/Python35/libs/python35.lib" debug "C:/Program Files/Python35/libs/python35_d.lib"
   ```

   It is valid value for a *library*, as long as it linked using [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_link_libraries.html) command.

   But again, in case of list, the `if()` line becomes incorrect. That is why you get the error message.
3. Finally, *EQUAL* compares *integers*, but strings are compared with *STREQUAL*.

Both 1 and 2 problems can be fixed by adding qoutes around variable's dereference.

As for assignment

```
set(PYTHON_LIBRARY "${${library_env}}")
```

it incorrectly process *list* variables, which is exactly you case. List variables should be referenced *without quotes* around them:

```
set(A_list ${B_list})
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should use _set()_ function to assign the value?`set(${library_env} "C:/Program Files/Python35/libs/python35.lib" "debug" "C:/Program Files/Python35/libs/python35_d.lib")` —— While I don't understand _target_link_library_ well, _set()_ is which I can use as a new hand. I don't know whether _set()_ is same with _target_link_library.

Comment: I'm very very sorry that I didn't write back to you in time.....Because these days is Spring Festival, I'm preparing for it. Thank you for your warm heart ! Thank you for your patience to help me. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I 'll keep on trying~

Comment: Now it don't prompt warning. _python library_ can be assigned to the parameter. And then I find the number of the parameter of the function _find()_ is wrong  I delete one of the function parameter. There does no error prompt.

Comment: the make file is clone from the [opencv](http://opencv.org/downloads.html). So I'm upset whether the operation is right.

Comment: I mean that original `cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake` is incorrect. While this file is not written by you, you may try to fix it to overcome error you get. But this doesn't mean that this is the only incorrectness in the code, and you may face with other errors... You may try another way for overcome the problem: if variable *PYTHON3_LIBRARY* exists in the cache (`CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory), then replace it content to `C:/Program Files/Python35/libs/python35.lib`. Probably, *single-valued* variable makes the script happy.

Comment: OK~Get it ~Thank you~